# SharePoint Calculated Column - Nested IF with dates and today's date

Tags: json, date, format

I have three columns: End_Date, Completion_Date, Status
If the Completion date is before the end date then the status is "On Time"
If the completion date is after the end date or today's date is after the end date, the status is "Late".

I've read that this will take today's date in JSON where the completion date doesn't have to be updated.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=floor((Number(@now)-Number([$End_Date]))/(1000*60*60*24))"
}
```

How can I nest the JSON if statement to accomplish what I need it to?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sahil, when I use the:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$End_Date] >= @now, 'On Time', 'Late')"
}
It shows Late on every one, even when the date is in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the if condition itself in the txtContent attribute. I've implemented the same requirement for you with the below JSON -

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$End_Date] >= @now, 'On Time', 'Late')"
}
```

Also, PFB the image for sample data run -

[image: Status]

Comment: Thank you. So to have two conditions, I would use an OR or nest another IF inside of it?

  "txtContent": "=if([$End_Date] >= @now, 'On Time', 'Late')" OR if([$End_Date] >= [Completion_Date], 'On Time', 'Late')"

Comment: You can put the OR condition in the first if condition only. I haven't tried this but you can write like this - "txtContent": "=if([$End_Date] >= @now || [$End_Date] >= [Completion_Date], 'On Time', 'Late')".. Also, Upvote my answer if it seems ok.